# How to know which key was held when left mouse button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I wan't to detect if some other key is held when the left mouse button is clicked how can i do it?
i used this to detect ctrl+shift but now i wan't to know if 'A' or 'B' or both were held.

```
if(e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) console.log("ctrl+shift key was held when pressing the left mouse button");
```

the mouse event I receive doesn't have a keyCode for held keys. I want pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure javascript solution would be:

```
var held_key = null;

function key_down(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  // get string representation of held key
  var keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);
  // store held key in global variable
  held_key = keychar;
}

//revert held_key to null onkeyup
function key_up(event) {
  var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
  held_key = null;
}

window.onload = function() {
  window.onkeydown = key_down;
  window.onkeyup = key_up;
  window.onclick = function(e) {
    // put condition for the key you want here
    if (held_key == 'A') {
      //do something
      console.log('hi!');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (listening for keydown and keyup):

```
var keys = [];

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var index = keys.indexOf(e.keyCode);

    if(index === -1){
        keys.push(e.keyCode);
    }
}).keyup(function(e){
    var index = keys.indexOf(e.keyCode);

    if(index !== -1){
        keys.splice(index, 1);
    }
}).click(function(e){
    console.log(keys);
});
```

Comment: that's jQuery, I need pure javascript.